# Error with os.system in python script

Tags: python, ffmpeg, os.system

I am creating a python script that will convert files using ffmpeg and unoconv. However when I run the program, rather than getting a converted file the program simply displays the text:

```
sh: 1: unoconv -f: not found
```

Here is the script for my program:

```
    path = raw_input("Please drag and drop the directory in which the file is stored into the terminal:")
    os.chdir(path[1:-2])
    filename = raw_input("Please enter the name of the file you would like to convert, including the file-type. e.g. test.txt, however please do make sure that the file-name does not have any spaces:")
    Fileextension = raw_input("What filetype would you like the program to convert your file to. E.g. .mp3: ")
    body, ext = os.path.splitext("filename")
    os.system("'ffmpeg -i ' + filename + body + Fileextension ")
```

Any ideas as to why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your command:

```
os.system("'ffmpeg -i ' + filename + body + Fileextension ")
```

You try to executed this literal string.

Try:

```
os.system('ffmpeg -i ' + filename + body + Fileextension)
```

Also, it is recommended to use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#module-subprocess) instead of `os.system`.

Comment: @kindall Should be just a file name:  `usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...`

Comment: @Mike Müller I tried this soluton, but when I did it i got no result. I only got the error code :  `:unoconv: you have to provide a filename as argument
Try unoconv -h'` for more information.` Do you have any idea as to how I can fix this.

Comment: Run it at the command line first. Make sure it works. Then print the command before executing it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the subprocess module, in particular [subprocess.check_call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) passing a list of args:

```
from subprocess import check_call
check_call(["ffmpeg" ,"-i",filename + body + Fileextension])
```

Any non-zero exit code will raise a `CalledProcessError`